# How to find and copy a table below a specified text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with multiple text labels followed by its respective tables.
I want to find a text and then copy the table immediately below it so i can paste it in other document.

```
Sub EWT()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim textA As String

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            textA = para.Range.Text
            Debug.Print textA
            'How to get the table just below this and copy it?
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: do you want to copy within the same document or...maybe you could add a screen shot presenting what you have and what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a general way of finding tables. In short, make a new range, assign the start of where the text leaves off, and the end is the end of the document. It'd be the first table. As an additional suggestion, avoid the Information function. One reason is it's slow.

> Sub EWT()
>       Dim para As Paragraph
>       Dim textA As String
>
> ```
> For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
>     If Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
>         textA = para.Range.Text
>         para.Range.Select 'Debug only
>
>         Dim myRange As Range
>         Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
>         myRange.Start = para.Range.End
>         myRange.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
>
>         Dim myTable As Table
>         Set myTable = myRange.Tables(1)
>         myTable.Select  'Debug only
>
>         Debug.Print textA
>         'How to get the table just below this and copy it?
>     End If
> Next End Sub
> ```

Then again, it looks like you're wanting to find every table in the document, since your Find doesn't look for any specific text, just text. If that's the case, this is quicker:

> Sub FindTables()
>       Dim myDocument As Document
>       Set myDocument = ActiveDocument
>
> ```
> Dim myTable As Table
> For Each myTable In myDocument.Tables
>     myTable.Select
> Next End Sub
> ```